# What does "out of nerves" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ... Hermione had been right; Professor Flitwick did indeed test them on Cheering Charms. Harry slightly overdid his **out of nerves** and Ron, who was partnering him, ended up in fits of hysterical laughter and had to be led away to a quiet room for an hour before he was ready to perform the charm himself. ...

I don't quite get what "**out of nerves**" means in this context. I've looked it up and it doesn't seem to be a set phrase. I guess it could mean "*Harry is nervous, so he slightly overdid his Cheering Charms*...". But I don't know if my understanding is correct. How should we understand it here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase **out of** means "because of" or "motivated by".

> She said that out of jealousy.

Because he was nervous.

P.S. But I should add that it sounds strange to my ear when used of something that is not truly a *motive* (fear, envy, jealousy, love, respect, anger, concern, etc).

Comment: I understand why @dan is confused, because I am too. Shouldn't it be "out of nerve", being nerve uncountable, to mean that Harry was nervous? Could it mean also that a sort of "no worries" spell, being "out of nerves" a kind of charm, was casted on Ron and it went wrong?

Comment: @RubioRic: **nerve** in the singular means *audacity* whereas **nerves** in the plural refers to "the jitters", the shaky and insecure feeling of nervousness.

Comment: @RubioRic The expression is *you're getting on my nerves*. (Although some people turn it into a joke and say *you're getting on my last nerve*.) Also, we refer to people as having *a case of the nerves* (not *a case of the nerve*). In general, expressions involving the word use it in a plural form. The one exception I can think of is when somebody says they are *getting up their nerve* to do something. But *nerve* is being used in a different sense in that expression.